# Почему не работает «Find Usage» в PhpStorm?

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm

Проблема всплыла около месяца-двух назад. Ранее всё работало корректно, во всех проектах.

Пытаюсь найти места, где используется класс с помощью `Ctrl + ПКМ` - получаю "No usage found in All Places".

[image: Не найдено]

Хотя даже производя поиск по имени класса - видно, что он используется в другом месте:

[image: На самом деле - используется]

Comment: Наверно ЛКМ, а не ПКМ ...

Comment: Какой фреймворк?

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, Yii2. Проблема возникла около двух месяцев назад - до этого всё было в норме. "Invalidate Cache", "Repair IDE" не помогли.

Comment: В Yii2 наблюдал такое,.. и сейчас на advanced проекте не всё хавает.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, перестал ещё работать "Refactor => Rename", изменения мгновенно отменялись.

Попробовал отключить плагин Yii2 Support - и всё заработало: и переименование, и поиск. И что самое интересное - проблема началась 2 месяца назад, и примерно тогда я и установил плагин.

Comment: Да, тож проверил; если отключить, то норм. Есть issue на GitHub'е: https://github.com/nvlad/yii2support/issues/268.